# CheckedListBox used from Python(pywin32)

Tags: python, windows, message, pywin32, checkedlistbox

Does anyone know how to get the list of items and check/uncheck items in a CheckedListBox from python?
I've found [this](http://www.brunningonline.net/simon/blog/archives/winGuiAuto.py.html) to help me partly on the way. I think I've found the handle for the CheckedListBox(listed as a SysTreeView32 by WinGuiAuto.py).

One usage will for my part be to create an autoinstaller that manages to uncheck all checkboxes that installs bloatware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [pywinauto](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywinauto/) I've managed to check items in a checkedlistbox by selecting them twice.

```
from pywinauto import application
app = application.Application()
app.Form1.CheckedListBox1.Select('item1')
app.Form1.CheckedListBox1.Select('item1')
```